# How to join one table with different tables with criteria API?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have following classes:

```
class A {
    private B b;
    // getters/setters
}
class B {
   private C c;
   private D d;
   // getters/setters
}
class C {
   private boolean outdated;
   // getters/setters
}
class D {
   // not important fields
   // getters/setters
}
```

Class B is connected to A, C and D with relation 'one-to-one'.

I am trying to join following tables with criteria api.

I have following code:

```
Root<A> root = query.from(A.class);
root.join(A_.b)
    .join(B_.c)
    .join(B_.d);
```

But unfortunately this code will not compile, I will get error on line with ".join(B_.d)", because after joining B with C I cannot use fields of B for joining.

The reason why I want to make such joins is because I need to have condition that entity C is not outdated (so I will add 'on' condition for it).

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root.join(A_.b).join(B_.c)` represents a `C`, so there is no way then to join to `"B_.d"`. You would need to do

```
Root<A> root = query.from(A.class);
Join<A,B> bJoin = root.join(A_.b);
bJoin.join(B_.c);
bJoin.join(B_.d);
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, joins in criteria api are not immutable, so I can just move every join into separated variable and work with them independently.